# From heat load to CFM and where does 400/ton come from?

Tags: ducts, central-heating, heat-pump

Based on [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/274750/24145) I have finally calculated my heating load of the total house as well as the distribution for individual ducts (rooms). Note that the formula for the heat loads was:

BTH/h = ∆T * Sigma

where Sigma is the sum of all areas multiplied by U-values encapsulating my to be conditioned space.
∆T = DesiredIndoorTemperature-MinOutdoorTemp = 68-40 = 28F (for me).

How do I now get from the heating load to CFMs so I can obtain required duct sizes?

The relationship should be:

CFM = (BTU/h)/(1.08*∆T)

Is this ∆T the same as we used for calculating the heat load? If yes, it cancels out and CFM is roughly given by the sum of all area times U value. Does not make sense to me. And even if, why do we bother then with ∆T?

If no, what do I choose for ∆T?

Furthermore, there is the general guideline of tonnage*400 to get CFM but nowhere an explanation of where this comes from. Is it related to the formula above?
If no, how can we derive it?
If yes, this would result in ∆T=30 which is not universal across the US.

Comment: Will you be air conditioning? What's the **solar gain** going to be like?  Solar gain can be the dominant factor in A/C requirements and that can dictate ducting.  Heating is a bit too easy; there's no such thing as solar *loss*.

Comment: No. It is a heat pump but it is used exclusively for heating. Hence I did not consider.

Answer (score 1):

400 CFM/ton is a rule of thumb because it works in a lot of scenarios. If you really want to know the correct CFM, look at the engineering data for the air handler you're planning to use. For example, the heat pump air handler in my home can be used at between 330 CFM/ton and 420 CFM/ton. In general it matters most for cooling. Lower CFM/ton rates will result in an increase in latent cooling capacity and a decrease in sensible cooling capacity. Higher CFM/ton rates will adjust the capacity in the other direction. If this is just for your home use, you can also design for the air velocities of the higher CFM/ton rate and turn it down later based on practical experience if needed. Assuming the larger ducts that math might lead to fit in the space, the worst thing you'll end up with is slightly lower than expected FPM and quieter ducts.

Comment: Thanks, so CFM=400xton has nothing to do with my formula above? When do I need the formula above then (and what is DeltaT in it)?

Comment: That formula comes out of ACCA Manual P, Section 3. If you plug 'how to read a psychometric chart' in to your favorite search engine that should get you a start on how all this relates. https://hvacrschool.com/room-sensible-heat/ for an example introduction article.

Comment: Yeah, low FPM in an airway is the least of your concerns in the residential world :)