Heating Options at high elevation in cold climate
Currently designing a 2500sqft house in the Sierra Nevada mountains at 6300ft elevation. It's an A-frame with a loft and living room area has high 20ft ceiling peak. It snows 4 months of the year, and summers are moderate with one or two 90˚ days. So I'm going to forego cooling, but considering options for primary heating:

Electric Radiant flooring: I was planning to use this for bathrooms under tile anyway, but why not just extend to the whole house?
I drew up a plan to lay about 820sqft of resistance wire mats through out the house totaling 10kW of power. I estimate the total cost would come out to $12k installed.

Traditional Forced Air Central System: No access to gas, so this would be electric too, probably sized around 3 Ton, which would be around 10.5kW. This will certainly cost me in the $20k range installed.

Heat pump system: I was advised heat pumps would not perform well at this elevation and climate where temps go below freezing for a significant part of the year.


I'm drawn to the electric radiant heat idea. It seems more efficient because of direct heat delivery as opposed to duct losses with a forced air system. I'd also be able to have multiple zones individually controllable. QuiteWarmth system
In the above described scenario, are there any other pros/cons to consider? Or suggestions on other energy or cost-efficient heating sources where natural gas is not available?
Edit 1: More specific question to make this less open-ended. Here's an electric radiant floor mat layout plan I drew up for the living floor, which is about 1800sqft.
Is 9.8kW worth of heating enough for this area?

Edit 2: Thanks for all the great answers and comments. Did a ton of research to get ball park numbers into a spreadsheet to understand how much it will cost and what is the breakeven point vs plain electric.
Two critical inputs are the heat pump efficiency at different temperatures. I looked through the manual of a 28kBTU copper+hunter unit and pulled out some COP figures that seemed reasonable. But it provided for heating:

COP @ 47F outside ~ 3.7
Rated capacity at 17F ~ 17kBTU
Max capacity at 5F = 21kBTU

Question 1: Why would the max capacity be higher at 5F compared to rated capacity at 17F? What is the difference between rated and max capacity?
Question 2: I assumed COP @ 47F is 3.5 and COP @ 17F is 1.5. Are these reasonable estimates?
Question 3: Very hard to find COP vs outside temp charts for most available units, so what average figure can I assume for COP @ 5C for example?
Question 4: Finding that it will take roughly 4-7 years to breakeven on the investment required for either heat pump or propane. Is this what one might expect vs going purely electric, or am I being too optimistic here with incorrect assumptions?

We do home improvement project troubleshooting here, not broad hypothetical questions. Please see the [help] for a refresher on what's appropriate to ask. Maybe you can revise to be more specific.

High ceilings do not help with heating costs.  Old heat pumps did not do well below freezing, but newer ones can be decent.  Electric heating does cost quite a bit when running, so should be examine.  Insulation/sealing from drafts is important to save heat costs.

Is pea coal delivery available in the area? Furnaces that burn pea coal (small pellets of anthracite) are available, similar to pellet furnaces. It's the cheapest source of heat per million BTU, a single delivery in the off season can last you a full year, and it uses very little electricity so it's easy to run on standby power if storms leave you blacked out.

Ask your neighbours about weather conditions.  Electric heat needs dependable power or a decent low/no electric secondary heat source(wood, propane, pea coal(never heard of) ) since electric heat takes a big generator(~20,000w) plus fuel if the power goes out

@isherwood revised with layout diagram and specific question.

@crip659 updated the post with a to-scale diagram showing 9.8kW of heating. Will also check with neighbors. Good point about power outage -- there will be a wood burning stove

@MTA, interesting but never heard of pea coal. I plan to have a wood burning stove, there is tons of free firewood around too.

How far below freezing? My heat pumps work to -15°F and some newer ones work even colder. But ground source heat pumps are the ultimate answer to that problem. "Why not electric radiant everywhere?" - "Why not just burn dollar bills in a stove?" Try it, your electric utility will love the income. Heat pumps give typically 3 times as much heat for the same electric input.

@Shubham -- have you looked at the current generation of cold-climate heatpumps (instead of That 70s Heat Pump)?

I'd be very surprised if you can't get propane. Not all gas requires a pipeline. Pretty common to have a buried 1000 gallon propane tank; but in my area, the cold climate heat pumps are cheaper to run.

when you have tall ceilings, ceiling fans go a long way in reducing costs of any heating setup.

@ThreePhaseEel I just did, and was surprised to find multi-zone systems that are ceiling mounted/recessed and outdoor handler operates at -13F. Is that really true? Where I plan to live, it probably won't ever go below +15F.

@Ecnerwal I checked with neighbors, seems like large propane tanks are the way to go. But I cannot imagine it being cheaper than electric heat.

@Shubham -- yeah, the newer cold-climate stuff has specs that knock That 70s Heat Pump out of the water, and it's steadily getting better and better too

It's really true. Or weally twuw, if you like cartoons. I have no other heat source, and my -15°F rated units have managed -16 or -17 actual on at least one occasion. At that point the COP drops near to 1 - most of the time it's much higher. As for "cost of propane .vs. cost of electricity" we'd need the price of each. A gallon of propane is 26.8 kWh (* efficiency of what you burn it in) which means it's roughly less than resistance electric if it's less than $5/gallon where I am in a 95% efficient unit. But it's less than heat pump electric (whole season) only if it's under $1.70

Thanks for al the awesome comments and answers. I posted an updated to the question above with a few more (hopefully not hypothetical and answerable) questions.

1 - Not sure; 2 - sounds reasonable to me but I'm not an expert and it will vary by system; 3 - don't know; 4 - if energy cost is only different by ~ $229 per year, not sure how you would recoup a $13,000 difference in installation cost in 4.7 years (same issue for gas) - 13000/229 = 56 years! On the other hand, I suspect you may be able to install the heat pump for less than $20k and it has the added benefit of air conditioning. But if breakeven is anything 20 years or more I would consider it as never breaking even on pure $ as these systems don't last forever.

Whoops, sorry that's Operating cost per month.
"Year" is a typo. I'll fix the picture.
The added benefit of ac cooling during a few weeks in summer sounds like perk.
Based on all of this, I'm inclined to a use a smaller mini split heat pump unit (maybe 1.5 ton?), with radiant to supplement

Just make sure you factor the months correctly - winter months x 180 hrs x running cost, etc. But that does make quite a difference. Don't undersize the units too much - I'd worry that 1.5 ton might not be enough, but there are a ton (pun intended) of variables.

Yep, I will check different combinations of usage and running cost to see how breakeven changes. I'm hoping 1.5ton is enough, might be able to squeeze 2Ton before NEC load calculation spills over 200A which would reset the cost analysis..

Total Cost of Ownership
While I am sure you are investing plenty in your dream house - and that's a great thing to do - since you actually bother to mention cost of installation of different systems, you are at least a little concerned about cost. So look at the total cost. That's:

Installation cost amortized over expected system lifetime
Running cost - calculated by cost of fuel x hours per year (or similar, there are multiple ways to do it but the results are roughly the same)

Since all of your proposed systems are electric, it comes down to resistance heat (whether radiant or central forced air) vs. heat pump. We already know some key numbers:

Installation of radiant = $12k
Installation of forced air = $20k

We don't know installation of a heat pump. My guess is that it would be a bit more than an electric resistance forced air system because (if central/forced air, though there are other options that might work) the outside parts of a heat pump will add significantly to the total cost. So let's guess $25k - but it could be more, I don't really know.
Running cost for radiant and forced air will be based purely on electric. Not surprisingly, they are nearly the same - 10 kW vs. 10.5 kW. In fact, I would expect the forced air system to use just a drop more than equivalent radiant heat because it takes electricity to run the fan. But we are talking about a 5% difference - basically noise.
However, a heat pump can easily achieve a significant improvement in efficiency, measured as COP. That number can easily be 2 or more, but it does generally decrease as the outside temperature decreases.
What we also don't know is how many hours your heat will need to run. If, for example, it runs 6 hours a day for six months of the year and 2 hours a day 3 months of the year (cold at night) and not at all for the hottest 3 months then you have:

(6 x 6 x 30) + (2 x 3 x 30) = 1,080 + 180 = 1,260 hours

Next we calculate the energy used:

Radiant = 1,260 x 10 kW = 12,600 kWh
Resistance Forced Air = 1,260 x 10.5 kW = 13,230 kWh
Heat Pump estimate COP 2 = 13,230 / 2 = 6,615 kWh
Heat Pump estimate COP 1.5 = 13,230 / 1.5 = 8,820 kWh

and then we apply an electric rate. It varies a bit, for now I'll use a nice simple $0.20 / kWh

Radiant = $2,520 per year
Resistance Forced Air = $2,646 per year
Heat Pump COP 2 = $1,323 per year
Heat Pump COP 1.5 = $1,764 per year

So it is quite plausible that a heat pump could save $1,000 or more per year. Meaning if you have an expected lifetime of 10 years (which I think is conservative but repairs do start to add up as well in later years), you could easily save $10,000 or more which would offset, and possibly exceed, the initial extra cost of a heat pump system.
So to proceed sensibly:

Try to determine how much your heat will need to run - heating degree days (which you can't control), insulation (which you can control) and other factors affect this quite a bit.
Get a couple of quotes on a heat pump system for the house to compare initial costs.
Determine COP based on heat pump specs combined with historic average temperatures for each month and then calculate an average COP for a "typical" year.
Find out local electric rates and whether they tend to be stable or fluctuate a lot.
Put it all together to determine TCO for each option.

There are other advantages/disadvantages to consider. Some people prefer radiant heat (warm floors), some prefer the hot blowing air of a forced air system. Radiant heat should be nearly maintenance free. A forced air system will have a blower, a heat pump will add quote a bit more active equipment. Make sure to factor expected equipment lifetime - vendors should be able to give you a rough idea even though nothing is generally guaranteed for more than a year.

12 years on Mitsubishi mini-split HPs installed by a Mitsubishi dealer, FYI. Depending on actual climate (the Sierra Nevada mountains are a rather long target to have no more specific location) ground source HP is surely worth considering, as the stable input temps from the ground mean a very consistent COP not dependent on outside temperature. Mini-splits do away with ductwork (and are much, much quieter to live with.) The self-installable units are considerably less expensive but likely have a shorter warranty as well.

If not for the work, a good wood stove plus tons of free firewood,  OP might only worry about installation costs.

@manassen thanks for the cost of ownership, I ran with it and tried to build a model   to compare 3 options. Added a few questions above if you have any further insight, would appreciate it!

Ah, you veered close to an answerable question - I'll run with it.
Whether any given amount of heating is adequate for a given space depends very much on the insulation of that space and the design-day temperature (which is either as cold as it ever gets there, or as cold as it gets there "normally" and on super cold days there should at least be enough heat the pipes don't freeze, [since design is typically for 68°F / 20°C inside temperature] and then it returns to the normal range.)
With zero information about the insulation or the actual design temperature, ("below freezing" offers a very wide range) the proposed amount of heating may be too much, not enough, or just right. Based on what look to be sliding glass doors, there are some large areas of poor insulation, and that requires enough heat to compensate for them dumping it outside.

See for an example of how to run the calculations: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/274750/18078

Thanks for the response. The architect is working on the calculations to come up with how much heating is actually needed to be code complaint. I guess my approach is more like "assume X amount of BTU heating is required, what does it cost now and to operate 3 different options to achieve this much heat"
